# Python expression evaluator and Interpreter pattern

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a simple expression evaluator in python,but I am stuck in parser method.Below is my code snippet.

```
    class Number:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value=value
    def execute(self):
        return self.value

class Plus:
    def __init__(self,left,right):
        self.left=left
        self.right=right
    def execute(self):
        return self.left+self.right

class Minus:
    def __init__(self,left,right):
        self.left=left
        self.right=right
    def execute(self):
        return self.left-self.right

class Multiply:
    def __init__(self,left,right):
        self.left=left
        self.right=right
    def execute(self):
        return self.left*self.right
import re
def parser(input):
    stack=[]
    token_pat = re.compile("\s*(?:(\d+)|(.))")
    for number, operator in token_pat.findall(input):


        if number:
            stack.append(Number(int(number)))

        else:
            first,second=stack.pop(),stack.pop()

            if operator=="+":
                stack.append(Plus(first,second))
            elif operator=="-":
                stack.append(Minus(first,second))
            elif operator=="*":
                stack.append(Multiply(first,second))
            else:
                raise SyntaxError("unknown operator")
    print stack[0].execute()


if __name__=="__main__":
    parser('1 2 +')
```

When I am running the above code,I am getting following error.Can anybody review my code .

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Interpreter.py", line 52, in <module>
    parser('1 2 +')
  File "Interpreter.py", line 48, in parser
    print stack[0].execute()
  File "Interpreter.py", line 12, in execute
    return self.left+self.right
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'instance' and 'in
```

Comment: And the question here is? The error message indicates clearly what your error is. Or? Where do you need help?

Comment: You're missing the recursion. Just use something like `self.left.execute()` and `self.right.execute()` everywhere and you should be fine.

Comment: @Emil,esael:My question is simple.I just wanted to know that where is mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is that confusing because you're using [classic classes](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes). With new-style classes (i.e. inheriting from `object`), you get a much more reasonable:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Number' and 'Number'
```

Either use `int`s instead of Number objects, or implement adding logic by implementing [`__add__` and friends](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__), or add evaluating logic in `Plus.execute`.

Also note that you're reimplementing Python's built-ins. Additionally, having an `execute` method is pretty much an anti-pattern. A much shorter implementation would be

```
import functools,operator,re

def parser(inp):
    stack=[]
    token_pat = re.compile("\s*(?:(\d+)|(.))")
    for number, op in token_pat.findall(inp):
        if number:
            stack.append(functools.partial(lambda i:i, int(number)))
        else:
            first,second=stack.pop(),stack.pop()
            try:
                op = {
                    '+': operator.add,
                    '-': operator.sub,
                    '*': operator.mul
                }[op]
            except KeyError:
                raise SyntaxError("unknown operator")

            stack.append(functools.partial(lambda op,first,second:
                        op(first(), second()), op, first, second))
    print(stack[0]())

if __name__=="__main__":
    parser('1 2 + 3 *')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for reviewing my code +1 for this.I am changing my code as per your instruction.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not interested doing basic debugging yourself:

```
sucmac: $ python out.py 
> /Users/xxxx/out.py(13)execute()
-> return self.left+self.right
(Pdb) self.left
<__main__.Number instance at 0x10043f3f8>
(Pdb) self.right
<__main__.Number instance at 0x10042f248>
(Pdb) right
*** NameError: name 'right' is not defined
(Pdb) self.right.__dict__
{'value': 1}
```

You obviously want

```
return self.right.value + self.left.value
```

Comment: You are obviously wrong, he wants recursive evaluation of the expressions.

Comment: On your machine, `python` seems to be aliased to something other than the generic cpython. Could you include how you set that up?